# MouseDown or MouseUp event?

Tags: user-interface, event-handling, controls, mousedown, mouseup

If you are trying to catch a right mouse click event on a control in order to select a cell in a grid or show a pop-up menu:

Which of the `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` events be used if these are the only two to choose from?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
Private Sub Form_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button = 2 Then
        PopupMenu test
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: My question is which of `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question in my mind. I came to this just by right clicking on Firefox screen, my desktop screen, and my Visual Studio IDE screen. If you keep right mouse button down and not release it, the menu *won't* show up in these programs. This means they placed the code in `MouseUp` event. So as a rule of thumb we'd better place it in `MouseUp` but my reason is not very conclusive.